# How to parse C-style comments with Alex lexer?

Tags: haskell, lexical-analysis, alex

NB. I'm using [this Alex template from Simon Marlow](https://github.com/simonmar/alex/blob/master/examples/haskell.x).

I'd like to create lexer for C-style comments. My current approach creates separate tokens for starting comments, ending, middle and oneline

```
%wrapper "monad"

tokens :-
  <0> $white+ ;
  <0> "/*"               { mkL LCommentStart `andBegin` comment }
  <comment> .            { mkL LComment }
  <comment> "*/"         { mkL LCommentEnd `andBegin` 0 }
  <0> "//" .*$           { mkL LSingleLineComment }

data LexemeClass
  = LEOF
  | LCommentStart
  | LComment
  | LCommentEnd
  | LSingleLineComment
```

- How can I reduce number of middle tokens? For input `/*blabla*/` I will get 8 tokens instead of one!
- How can I strip the `//` part from single line comment token?
- Is it possible to lex comments without `monad` wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this:

http://lpaste.net/107377

Test with something like:

```
echo "This /* is a */ test" | ./c_comment
```

which should print:

```
Right [W "This",CommentStart,CommentBody " is a ",CommentEnd,W "test"]
```

The key alex routines you need to use are:

```
alexGetInput -- gets the current input state
alexSetInput -- sets the current input state
alexGetByte  -- returns the next byte and input state
andBegin     -- return a token and set the current start code
```

Each of the routines `commentBegin`, `commentEnd` and `commentBody` have the following signature:

```
AlexInput -> Int -> Alex Lexeme
```

where `Lexeme` stands for the your token type. The `AlexInput` parameter has the form (for the monad wrapper):

(AlexPosn, Char, [Bytes], String)

The `Int` parameter is the length of the match stored in the `String` field. Therefore the form of most token handlers will be:

```
handler :: AlexInput -> Int -> Alex Lexeme
handler (pos,_,_,inp) len = ... do something with (take len inp) and pos ...
```

In general it seems that a handler can ignore the `Char` and `[Bytes]` fields.

The handlers `commentBegin` and `commentEnd` can ignore both the `AlexInput` and `Int` arguments because they just match fixed length strings.

The `commentBody` handler works by calling `alexGetByte` to accumulate the comment body until "*/" is found. As far as I know C comments may not be nested so the comment ends at the first occurrence of "*/".

Note that the first character of the comment body is in the `match0` variable. In fact, my code has a bug in it since it will not match "/**/" correctly. It should look at `match0` to decide whether to start at `loop` or `loopStar`.

You can use the same technique to parse "//" style comments - or any token where a non-greedy match is required.

Another key point is that patterns like `$white+` are qualified with a start code:

```
<0>$white+
```

This is done so that they are not active while processing comments.

You can use another wrapper, but note that the structure of the `AlexInput` type may be different -- e.g. for the basic wrapper it is just a 3-tuple: `(Char,[Byte],String)`. Just look at the definition of `AlexInput` in the generated .hs file.

A final note... accumulating characters using `++` is, of course, rather inefficient. You probably want to use `Text` (or `ByteString`) for the accumulator.

Comment: Great! I thought one must try to write more rules, less explicit lexing. But searching for rule-base approach I found only "/*" (([^\*])|(\*+[^\/\*]))*\** "*/" { mkL LComment}, which must less efficient then your solution

Comment: Yes - if you can find a greedy regexp you can use that. But if, for example, your comments can nest it seems you'll have to roll your own using `alexGetByte` and friends.

Comment: The link is broken